calling a function across all values in a column, pandas
I am attempting a (fairly remedial) function call across a specific column, obviously with the goal of calling it across all index rows. But for some reason, the output is a repetition of an index that is not the first or last row in the dataframe.
function:
def split_and_order(string_samp):
    return string_samp.split(",")

call:
sorted_list = [split_and_order(j) for j in michelin["FacilitiesAndServices"]]

output:
[['Air conditioning',
  'Car park',
  'Interesting wine list',
  'Restaurant offering vegetarian menus',
  'Wheelchair access'],
 ['Air conditioning',
  'Car park',
  'Interesting wine list',
  'Restaurant offering vegetarian menus',
  'Wheelchair access'],
 ['Air conditioning',
  'Car park',
  'Interesting wine list',
  'Restaurant offering vegetarian menus',
  'Wheelchair access'],
 ['Air conditioning',
  'Car park',
  'Interesting wine list',
  'Restaurant offering vegetarian menus',
  'Wheelchair access'],
 ['Air conditioning',
  'Car park',
  'Interesting wine list',
  'Restaurant offering vegetarian menus',
  'Wheelchair access']]

actual data:
0                   Air conditioning,Wheelchair access
1          Air conditioning,Car park,Wheelchair access
2          Air conditioning,Car park,Wheelchair access
3    Air conditioning,Car park,Garden or park,Inter...
4    Air conditioning,Interesting wine list,Wheelch...
5    Air conditioning,Interesting wine list,Restaur...
Name: FacilitiesAndServices, dtype: object

bring on the wisdom... what is the correct way to call a function across all values in a pandas dataframe? does this require a lambda function?

What is your expected output?

actual data as shown above, split into a list by comma

The code looks correct. I tested and, it is giving the expected output. Look into your variable name, df  name etc. closely

same problem. double checked my variable names. same thing with using a lambda function. michelin['sorted_list'] = michelin.apply(lambda x: split_and_order(x['FacilitiesAndServices']), axis=1), the same repeated values.

data comes from this repo here https://github.com/plotly/datasets/blob/master/michelin_by_Jerry_Ng.csv, if you're curious

Try this:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'FacilitiesAndServices': ['Air conditioning,Car park,Wheelchair access', 'Air conditioning,Car park,Garden or park']})
df['FacilitiesAndServices'] = df['FacilitiesAndServices'].str.split(',', expand=False)
df

                             FacilitiesAndServices
0  [Air conditioning, Car park, Wheelchair access]
1     [Air conditioning, Car park, Garden or park]


yep, that works well enough. Any idea why I'm not able to call a function across the column in the same way?

To use the specific example here (split strings), pandas supports this natively:
df['output_column'] = df['input_column'].str.split(",")

More generally, to apply a function to all cells in a specific column:
df['output_column'] = df['input_column'].map(my_function)

Unrelated: in the example, there are a couple issues with split_and_order. First, the arg name shadows a built-in module string. Second, that name is not used afterwards, using string_samp instead - perhaps, a typo.

yes, that is a typo. fixed.

that's so interesting - so you can't call a function without mapping it?
Would a lambda function also work here?

@plotmaster473 you can call a function without mapping, and what you did with a list comprehension should work (and works with gtomer data example). However, it is more efficient to use a pandas built-in specifically for that. Knowing it's a pandas object, it can do some memory optimizations, and in some scenarios allow for parallelization (not out of the box, though)

got it, thanks. I'll use the built in functionality for now.

@plotmaster473 also, yes - a lambda would work with .map()
